# RegExp - how to match only those words which are in boundaries? \b not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string "btn btn-block btn-red btn-". How do I find only "btn-" ? In JavaScript \b works fine for "btn-block" but it breaks when it ends with a hyphen. When I use /\bbtn-\b/ it selects "btn-block" and "btn-red" but not the actual "btn-" which I want. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a demo?

Comment: http://regexr.com/3ggh5 this one is problematic

Comment: http://regexr.com/3ggh8 this one works fine

Comment: If you only want to match "btn-" at the end of a string then `\b/btn-$/ will do, but it is not clear what you want.

Comment: In Chrome `'btn-block btn- btn-red'.match(/\bbtn-\b/)[0]` gives me `btn-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group 1` from this should work `\b(btn-)(\s|$)`

Answer (score 1):

use this one   `/btn-/g` or `/btn-/gi` to ignore cases
try this http://www.regviz.org/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "find". If you mean "If it exists in the string, return true" then this will work:

```
var myString = "btn btn-block btn-red btn-";
var myStringTwo = "btn btnblock";

// This will print "Found btn- in myString"
if(myString.search(/btn-/) > -1)
    console.log("Found btn- in myString");
else
    console.log("Couldn't find btn- in myString");

// This will print "Couldn't find btn- in myStringTwo"
if(myStringTwo.search(/btn-/) > -1)
    console.log("Found btn- in myStringTwo ");
else
    console.log("Couldn't find btn- in myStringTwo");
```

Comment: i meant find all "btn-" within a string but not followed by or preced by anything like "btn-block". /btn-/ selects both "btn-" - which is what I want and "btn-block" which is not what I want